# What order were the Pauline epistles written, according to evangelical critical scholarship?

Tags: new-testament, paul-apostle, textual-criticism, epistles

I am unaware whether this is a hotly contested issue or not, but if it is, I would be looking for the majority opinion among evangelical scholars, that is, scholars who affirm Pauline authorship, inerrancy, and the various other doctrines that make a scholar an evangelical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both "majority opinion" and "evangelical" (even with the guidelines you supplied) are slippery terms. They'll probably always be in a state of flux, so it's difficult to supply exactly what you've asked for. But don't panic. I think a relatively clear picture can still emerge.

I've decided to give a sampling of three scholars who I think are firmly within the evangelical camp: [Dan Wallace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_B._Wallace), [J. Hampton Keathley III](https://bible.org/users/j-hampton-keathley-iii), and [Luke Timothy Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_Timothy_Johnson). For [Wallace](https://bible.org/series/new-testament-introductions-and-outlines) and [Keathley](https://bible.org/seriespage/4-pauline-epistles) I found dates, but for [Johnson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/080063439X) I was only able to find an order. Note that Johnson groups together 1-2 Corinthians, 1-2 Thessalonians, and the Pastorals as one unit each.

```
+-----------------+----------+---------+---------+
|                 | Keathley | Wallace | Johnson |
+-----------------+----------+---------+---------+
| Romans          | 57-58    | 56-57   |       4 |
| 1 Corinthians   | 55       | spr 54  |       2 |
| 2 Corinthians   | 56       | fall 55 |       2 |
| Galatians       | 49 or 55 | fall 48 |       3 |
| Ephesians       | 60-61    | c 60    |       8 |
| Philippians     | 60-61    | c 60    |       5 |
| Colossians      | 61       | c 60    |       7 |
| 1 Thessalonians | 51-52    | spr 50  |       1 |
| 2 Thessalonians | 51-52    | sum 50  |       1 |
| 1 Timothy       | 63-66    | 63      |       9 |
| 2 Timothy       | 67       | 64      |       9 |
| Titus           | 62-67    | 63      |       9 |
| Philemon        | 61       | c 60    |       6 |
+-----------------+----------+---------+---------+
```

<sub>*Table formatting [provided by Senseful Solutions](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html).*</sub>

If we consider the same units Johnson does and add the Prison Letters (Ephesians, Philippians, Colossians, Philemon), then we have exactly 6 "units" or "chunks" of letters that need ordering: Romans, 1-2 Corinthians, Galatians, Prison Letters, 1-2 Thessalonians, Pastorals. Using that schema, here's the above table simplified:

```
+----------------+----------+---------+---------+
|                | Keathley | Wallace | Johnson |
+----------------+----------+---------+---------+
| Romans         | 3        |       4 |       4 |
| Corinthians    | 4        |       3 |       2 |
| Galatians      | 1 or 2   |       1 |       3 |
| Prison Letters | 5        |       5 |       5 |
| Thessalonians  | 1 or 2   |       2 |       1 |
| Pastorals      | 6        |       6 |       6 |
+----------------+----------+---------+---------+
```

From here, as promised, a clear picture emerges. The consensus is that **the Thessalonian letters were the first or second written, Galatians was also early, Romans was written third or fourth, the Prison Letters were later, and the Pastorals last** (shortly before the end of his life). The only major point of disagreement is where the Corinthian letters fit in, which is a very complex question as you can [read in Wallace](https://bible.org/seriespage/2-corinthians-introduction-argument-and-outline) (look for the phrase "special problem").

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. It's a very hard question to ask in such a way that is in scope for this site, without first already knowing the answer.